# Eclipse4 export product: An error occured while collecting items to be installed

Tags: eclipse-rcp

when I try to export my e4 rcp (which is working fine within eclipse) I get the following error:

[image]

Any ideas what that means?

Edit: I export the product with the eclispe export product wizard. If i uncheck the checkbox "Generate p2 repository" everything works fine. Which leads me to my next question? What is this repository and why would I need it?

Comment: How are you doing the export?

Comment: I'm using the product file of my application. There is a menu entry called Exporting:  Use the Eclispe Product export wizard to package and export the product defined in this configuration.

Comment: You are probably missing a dependency in the .product file

Comment: The plugins stated in the error message are all on the dependencies list of of my .product file.

Comment: The p2 repository is what you need for an install location in  `Available Software Sites` in the Install/Update preferences. It used to be called an 'update site'

Comment: I assume I won't need it then. Thank you again for helping me out!